# extracting and counting unique columns from an SQL query with multiple joins

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, join

I'm trying to work out how to select X number of unique values from one given column in the result from an SQL query with multiple joins which produces some duplication that requires filtering back down (post query) once the X number of unique values have been found.

A simple example might be a result containing a one to many relationship of user id’s and the names of countries they have visited.

So it might take 40, 60 or 6000 rows of results to get 10 individual people, but 10 is the required parameter in the query, and the actual number of rows to return is whatever it takes to achieve that number of unique people.

If it’s not too much info, I thought I would reference my real PHP/MYSQL example.

In this example, I am selecting, say 10 USER_IDs at a time from a query to find users best matched by their distance from a given point, then by the weighting of any instrument they play, then by the weighting of any styles that they play. (The weighting of styles and instruments indicates each members interest or skill level, where 1 is their favourite or best).

Because the style and instrument weightings are integral to the order of the results, I think I need to run one biq query with multiple joins, to get everything in the right order of preference for results. ) As opposed to just searching by distance and then looping through those results in another query looking at joining up the instruments and styles info.

Some relevant tables and their columns.

**members:**

```
USER_ID 
PASSWORD
FIRST_NAME  
LAST_NAME           
BIO         
BIO_IMAGE       
WILL_CONNECT_STATUS 
PROFILE_COMPLETE    
EMAIL                   
SIGNUP_DATE                 
LAST_LOGIN              
ACCOUNT_TYPE    
EMAIL_ACTIVATED     
NOTIFY_MSG  int(11)     
NOTIFY_CONN_REQ 
NOTIFY_PROF_CHANGE  
LATITUDE    
LONGTITUDE
```

**members_inst:**

```
ID
USER_ID
INSTRUMENT_ID
ACTIVE
WEIGHT
```

**instruments:**

```
id
name
active
```

**members_styles:**

```
ID
USER_ID
STYLE_ID
ACTIVE
WEIGHT
```

**styles:**

```
id
style
active
```

Here’s a test query as I have it so far. It seems to give me a cascading one to many result set with everything in the right order. I know my LIMIT parameter is not going to give me what I need, but it’s that result range that I want to shift from raw number of rows returned, to number of unique values in the m.USER_ID column. I just need to be able to select a range of the 'ones' in the 'one to many' - eg 1-10, 11-20 and so on. Some sort of loop that detects new values for m.USER_ID as a means for detecting the beginning and end of the required range is what I think I’m after.

```
SELECT 
    m.USER_ID, 
    m.FIRST_NAME, 
    m.LAST_NAME, 
    m.LATITUDE, 
    m.LONGTITUDE, 
    mi.INSTRUMENT_ID, 
    i.name, 
    mi.WEIGHT AS MI_WEIGHT, 
    ms.STYLE_ID, 
    s.style, ms.WEIGHT AS MS_WEIGHT,( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(-38.14854370) ) * cos( radians( LATITUDE ) ) * cos( radians( LONGTITUDE ) - radians(144.36134790) ) + sin( radians(-38.14854370) ) * sin( radians( LATITUDE ) ) ) ) 
AS distance 
    FROM members m 
        INNER JOIN members_inst mi
        ON m.USER_ID = mi.USER_ID

        INNER JOIN instruments i
        ON mi.INSTRUMENT_ID = i.id

        INNER JOIN members_styles ms
        ON m.USER_ID = ms.USER_ID

        INNER JOIN styles s
        ON ms.STYLE_ID = s.id

        WHERE mi.ACTIVE=1 AND i.active=1 AND mi.WEIGHT != -1 AND ms.WEIGHT!=-1
        HAVING distance < 1000 AND USER_ID!= 1 ORDER BY distance, MI_WEIGHT, MS_WEIGHT LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Comment: So the 'lighter' weights are more important. That's a pity. :-(

Comment: I could switch them without too many problems.

Comment: As a result, you want 10 different users, that's it ? (i.e. the same user do not appear twice with different styles or instruments in the result)

Comment: Yes. I would hope to render 10 names at a time, along with their instruments and styles (regardless of how many in those two lists) and the names listed in order of distance, then instrument weight, then style weight, those orders being derived from the full result set (before being collapsed down to unique names).

Answer (score 0):

First you need subqueries to find the instrument and the style with best weight for each user. For the instrument :

```
SELECT mi.USER_id,max(i.weight) as max_i_weight
FROM members_inst mi INNER JOIN instruments i ON mi.INSTRUMENT_ID = i.id
WHERE i.weight!=-1 and mi.ACTIVE=1 and i.active=1
GROUP BY mi.USER_ID
```

and for the style :

```
SELECT ms.USER_id,max(s.weight) as max_s_weight
FROM members_style ms INNER JOIN styles s ON ms.STYLE_ID = s.id
WHERE s.weight!=-1
GROUP BY ms.USER_ID
```

Those queries are useful to later sort user according to maximum weight for instrument and style.

Then, join the different tables to build the information and sort the users by distance, max instrument weight and max style weight (known from the above queries).

```
SELECT 
    m.USER_ID, 
    m.FIRST_NAME, 
    m.LAST_NAME, 
    m.LATITUDE, 
    m.LONGTITUDE, 
    mi.INSTRUMENT_ID, 
    i.name, 
    max_i_weight, 
    ms.STYLE_ID, 
    s.style,
    max_s_weight,
    6371 * acos( cos( radians(-38.14854370) ) * cos( radians( LATITUDE ) ) * cos( radians( LONGTITUDE ) - radians(144.36134790) ) + sin( radians(-38.14854370) ) * sin( radians( LATITUDE ) ) ) AS distance
FROM members m INNER JOIN members_inst mi ON m.USER_ID = mi.USER_ID
   INNER JOIN (SELECT mi.USER_ID,max(i.weight) as max_i_weight
               FROM members_inst mi INNER JOIN instruments i ON mi.INSTRUMENT_ID = i.id
               WHERE i.weight!=-1 and mi.ACTIVE=1 and i.active=1
               GROUP BY mi.USER_ID) best_instrument ON m.USER_ID=best_instrument.USER_ID
       INNER JOIN instruments i ON mi.INSTRUMENT_ID = i.id AND best_instrument.max_i_weight=i.weight
           INNER JOIN members_styles ms ON m.USER_ID = ms.USER_ID
               INNER JOIN (SELECT ms.USER_id,max(s.weight) as max_s_weight
                           FROM members_style ms INNER JOIN styles s ON ms.STYLE_ID = s.id
                           WHERE s.weight!=-1
                           GROUP BY ms.USER_ID) best_style ON m.USER_ID=best_style.USER_ID
                   INNER JOIN styles s ON ms.STYLE_ID = s.id  AND best_style.max_s_weight=s.weight
WHERE USER_ID!= 1
GROUP BY m.USER_ID
HAVING distance < 1000
ORDER BY distance, max_i_weight, max_s_weight
LIMIT 0 , 10;
```

The result should be the list of the ten first users (without any duplicate) by increasing distance, then increasing instrument weight, then increasing style weight.
I do not try it, but it should work, except some typos...